# How to send a post request for file input in javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom, file-upload, input

I wrote this program to help me send post request by javascript

only the elements with send class will be sent

I store all data in a variable, because this can be re-used in another ajax function.

and then use it to create form and send it out.

this can send any data in the page, not just form input element

but it cannot send file, because I don't know how to store file input element to variable, and then create input file element for that file.

Is it possible to make my program to handle file input?

```
function send(url)
{
    var data=getData();
    var form=document.createElement('form');
    form.setAttribute('method', 'POST');
    form.setAttribute('action', url);
    for(x in data)
    {
        var hidden=document.createElement('input');
        hidden.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
        hidden.setAttribute('name', x);
        hidden.setAttribute('value', data[x]);
        form.appendChild(hidden);
    }
    document.body.appendChild(form);
    form.submit();
}

function getData()
{
    var data={};
    var sendNode = document.getElementsByClassName('send');
    for(var x=0; x<sendNode.length; x++)
    {
        var node=sendNode[x];
        if(node.nodeName=='INPUT')
        {
            var nodeType=node.type;
            if(nodeType=='check')
            {
                if(data[node.getAttribute('name')])
                {
                    data[node.getAttribute('name')].push(node.value);
                }
                else
                {
                    var arr=[node.value];
                    data[node.getAttribute('name')] = arr;
                }

            }
            else if(nodeType=='radio')
            {
                if(node.checked)
                {
                    data[node.getAttribute('name')] = node.value;
                }
            }
            else //text, password, email
            {
                data[node.getAttribute('name')] = node.value;
            }
        }
        else if(node.nodeName=='SELECT' || node.nodeName=='TEXTAREA')
        {
            data[node.getAttribute('name')] = node.value;
        }
        else
        {
            data[node.getAttribute('data-name')] = node.innerHTML;
        }

    }
    return data;
}
```

Comment: Can I ask what you're trying to accomplish? Isn't standard method="post" good for you?

Comment: If I want to submit the data in div, span, li...etc, standard method cannot do that, so I implement my own submit function.

Comment: Well right way to do that should be to send input type="hidden" fields. Files are pretty tricky so you simply (unless you find a security hole) cannot do that. For files you may take a look to File API (in modern browsers).